# add activity to settings in android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, application-settings

I want to add an `About Us` TextView to my android app. I know that each android device has a button that takes users to `settings`. So how do I add an activity to `settings`? I am not using the action bar technology yet. I am referring to the hardware button for settings.

Comment: There is no button for "settings". On newer devices there is no button **at all**. On Older devices there is a "menu" button. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html

Answer (score -1):

At an about_us item in the menu layout in the res --> menu folder. Then in your MainActivity override onOptionsItemSelected to launch your About Us activity.

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
    switch (item.getItemId())
    {
        case R.id.about_us:

            // launch about us activity
            return true;

        case R.id.menu_settings:
            // launch settings if any
            return true;

        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: @Pouton Gerald want to add his activity to android os's setting, not app's  setting,I think